# How to find `.strtab` in an ELF file?

Tags: c, elf, readelf

When running `readelf -S` I get:

```
  [27] .strtab           STRTAB           0000000000000000  00001630
       00000000000001d7  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [28] .shstrtab         STRTAB           0000000000000000  00001807
       0000000000000103  0000000000000000           0     0     1
```

How can I get the index of `.strtab`?
At first I tried to detect it using the `Type` field, but that won't work as you can see (27 and 28 have same type). Plus I can't be sure that it will be the first of type STRTAB to appear.

My struct with some explanations:

```
/*
 * Section header.
 */
typedef struct {
    Elf64_Word sh_name;    /* Section name (index into the
                       section header string table). */
    Elf64_Word sh_type;    /* Section type. */
    Elf64_Xword sh_flags;    /* Section flags. */
    Elf64_Addr sh_addr;    /* Address in memory image. */
    Elf64_Off sh_offset;    /* Offset in file. */
    Elf64_Xword sh_size;    /* Size in bytes. */
    Elf64_Word sh_link;    /* Index of a related section. */
    Elf64_Word sh_info;    /* Depends on section type. */
    Elf64_Xword sh_addralign;    /* Alignment in bytes. */
    Elf64_Xword sh_entsize;    /* Size of each entry in section. */
} Elf64_Shdr;
```

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: [Distinguish .shstrtab and .strtab in ELF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64967077/distinguish-shstrtab-and-strtab-in-elf-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I get the index of `.strtab`?

You read the `Elf64_Shdr`s one by one. When you've read the 28th entry, you will have read the `.strtab`, and you'll know its index.

You'll know that it's the `.strtab` section by comparing its name with `".strtab"` string literal.

(You are probably intending to ask a different question, but if that's the case, you haven't expressed it well.)

**Update:**

> Can't I do anything else rather than comparing strings

Maybe. If your real question is finding the `.strtab` section, then not really.

> (which is somehow hard) can I assume it will be the first STRTAB in the file for example?

There is no guarantee that that will be the case.

Note: if you are worried about the speed of `strcmp()`, note that you can only do that `strcmp()` when `.sh_type == SHT_STRTAB`, and since there are usually at most two such sections in any given file, the concern about the speed of `strcmp()` is likely misplaced. Your code would look something like:

```
  if (shdr.sh_type == SHT_STRTAB) {
    const char *sh_name = contents_of_shstrab + shdr.sh_name;
    if (strcmp(sh_name, ".strtab") == 0) {
      /* found .strtab; do whatever you need with it */
    }
  }
```

**Update 2:**

> your solution is wrong, please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68074508/

You can't claim that my solution is wrong, since I haven't provided a complete solution. It is also *not* wrong.

Here is complete code (with most error checking omitted):

```
#include <elf.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <link.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (argc < 1) return 1;

  int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
  if (fd == -1) return 2;

  struct stat st_buf;
  if (fstat(fd, &st_buf) != 0) return 3;

  char *data = mmap(NULL, st_buf.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
  if (data == MAP_FAILED) return 4;

  const ElfW(Ehdr) *ehdr = (const ElfW(Ehdr) *)data;
  const ElfW(Shdr) *shdr = (const ElfW(Shdr) *)(data + ehdr->e_shoff);

  const char *shstrtab = data + shdr[ehdr->e_shstrndx].sh_offset;

  for (int j = 0; j < ehdr->e_shnum; j++) {
    printf("[%2d] %s\n", j, shstrtab + shdr[j].sh_name);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc -g t.c -Wall
$ ./a.out ./a.out
[ 0]
[ 1] .interp
[ 2] .note.gnu.build-id
[ 3] .note.ABI-tag
[ 4] .gnu.hash
[ 5] .dynsym
[ 6] .dynstr
...
[32] .symtab
[33] .strtab
[34] .shstrtab
```

Comment: Can't I do anything else rather than comparing strings (which is somehow hard) can I assume it will be the first STRTAB in the file for example?

Comment: "If your real question is finding the .strtab section, then not really." yes that's what I want, what you mean?

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand what you are asking. I showed how to enumerate all sections and print their names. If you _literally_ need to find a section named `.strtab`, then the solution is to go over sections until you find one that is named `.strtab` (using `strcmp`). There is no way to avoid `strcmp` (or equivalent).

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, string parsing is not necessary I think:

> How can I get the index of .strtab?

The `sh_link`-member of the `Elf64_Shdr`-struct points to the index of the section header containing the string table (`.strtab`) if one is present.

```
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
                                     ...
  [34] .symtab           SYMTAB           0000000000000000  00003790
       0000000000000438  0000000000000018          35    20     8
  [35] .strtab           STRTAB           0000000000000000  00003bc8
       0000000000000283  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [36] .shstrtab         STRTAB           0000000000000000  00003e4b
       000000000000016a  0000000000000000           0     0     1
```

In the example above, notice how the `.symtab` section header contains the value of `35` for `sh_link` which is precisely the section header index of
`.strtab`.

This is also what readelf uses to figure out the offset of the `.strtab`.